# How do I get a free version (non-trial) of the compiler "Cuda Fortran"?

Tags: cuda, fortran

I searched for free cuda fortran compiler and found only PGI compiler, which is non-free. Maybe I got something wrong?

Comment: correct AFAIK.  You can get a [free trial of the PGI compiler](http://www.pgroup.com/support/trial.htm).  It's also possible to write your CUDA code in C, and link it with other Fortran (non-CUDA) modules.

Comment: As I understood their trial is a bit "tricky" - yes, you can develop with it for 15 days and even run your programs, but when this 15 days end you have two options - wait six month for another 15 day trial without any capability of running built applications or buy the compiler for abnormally high price.

Comment: You're better off using GPU libraries anyway.  GPU compilers don't come close to the performance that hand-tuned libraries are achieving today.

Comment: In my experience if you are at a research institution your employer may already have a PGI license. PGI's prices seem reasonable -- comparable to Intel compiler pricing, probably lower.

Comment: PGI Accelerator and CUDA Fortran are separate products. Most institutions have only licenses of the normal compiler. CUDA Fortran is a proprietary format, no established standard. I don't know if construction of an alternative compiler would be legal at all (patents).

Comment: @gpu There are certainly not libraries for every type of problem one has to solve. I don't know how are they interoperable and share GPU memory between calls of different GPU libraries.

Comment: @VladimirF In the GPU space, the functional coverage provided by libraries is greater than that provided by compilers (making the logical assumption that something is not functionally covered unless it actually provides performance benefit).  The top libraries all have the ability to pass device pointers between them with ease.

Comment: @gpu The libraries are compiled with something other than compilers?

Comment: @VladimirF My comments are limited to paid compilers and compilers that try to auto-parallelize. Yes, compilers are great at compiling, just not at auto-detecting GPU data-parallelism.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed there is currently no free implementation of CUDA Fortran. As an alternative, if you are willing to code just the CUDA kernels of your program in C/C++, you can call C functions from Fortran. See, for example, [this post](http://www.computationalmathematics.org/topics/files/calling_cuda_from_fortran.html).

As a lower-cost option, CAPS provides an [OpenACC compiler for Fortran for $199](http://blogs.nvidia.com/2012/06/openacc-complier-fast-portable-just-199-from-caps/). I realize it is not exactly CUDA Fortran, and it is not free, but it may be useful to you or other Fortran programmers.

Comment: The first offer, CUDA in C and call from Fortran, is really creative!

Comment: @ahmad, it's not creative - it is what one normally does when faced with C-only APIs like CUDA.

Comment: @Hristo Iliev, didn't you feel sarcasm in ahmad's post?

Comment: @user983302, it might be the exclamation mark, it might be not...

Comment: When calling CUDA libraries (including CUDA Runtime API) and functions  in C which call CUDA C kernels, you can use `iso_c_bindings` intrinsic module from Fortran 2003 standard.